# How to Prove It, Exercise 6.5.9

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, relations

> Suppose $R$ is a relation on $A$ and $S$ is the transitive closure of $R$. If $(a, b) \in S$, then there is some positive integer $n$ such that $(a, b) \in R^n$, and therefore by the well-ordering principle, there must be a smallest such $n$. We define the distance from $a$ to $b$ to be the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $(a, b) \in R^n$, and we write $d(a, b)$ to denote this distance.
>
> (a) Suppose that $(a, b)$ and $(b, c)$ (and therefore $(a, c) \in S$ since $S$ is transitive). Prove that $d(a, b) \leq d(a, b) + d(b, c)$.
>
> (b) Suppose $(a, c) \in S$ and $0 < m < d(a, c)$. Prove that there is some $b \in A$ such that $d(a, b) = m$ and $d(b, c) = d(a, c) - m$.

Here are my attempts at proving the above. Are they correct?

**Proof of (a):**

Let $d(a, b) = m$ and $d(b, c) = n$. Then $(a, b) \in R^m$ and $(b, c) \in R^n$. Therefore $(a, c) \in R^n \circ R^m = R^{n + m}.$ Let,

$$
T = \{ q : (a, c) \in R^q \}.
$$

Then it follows that $m + n \in T$. Since the smallest element of $T$ is $d(a, c)$ we must have that,

$$
d(a, c) \leq m + n = d(a, b) + d(b, c). \square
$$

**Proof of (b):**

Let $n = d(a, c)$. Then $(a, c) \in R^n = R^{n - m} \circ R^m$. This means that there exists a $b \in A$ such that $(a, b) \in R^m$ and $(b, c) \in R^{n - m}$. Hence $d(a, b) \leq m$ and $d(b, c) \leq n - m$. We also have from part (a) that,

$$
d(a, c) \leq d(a, b) + d(b, c).
$$

Now suppose that $d(a, b) < m$. Then we would have,

$$
d(a, c) \leq d(a, b) + d(b, c) < m + n - m = n
$$

which is impossible since $d(a, c) = n$. So $d(a, b) = m$. Similarly, if we suppose that $d(b, c) < n - m$ we are led to the contradiction that $d(a, c) < n$. Hence, $d(b, c) = n - m$.

So there is some $b \in A$ such that $d(a, b) = m$ and $d(b, c) = d(a, c) - m$. $\square$

I think the proof of part (a) is correct but I'm not so sure about part (b). The reason I think part (b) might not be correct is that this exercise is from the chapter on induction and I haven't used induction in the proof.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Okay, thanks very much!

Comment: You’re welcome!